# Adding to EntitySet not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm, database-first

I'm trying to add an object to a database-first ORM EntitySet in an MVC project.  I use a piece of code something like this:

```
public static Boolean CreateListing(string title, string description)
{
    ListingEntities ce = new ListingEntities();
    ce.Ads.AddObject(new Ad()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Title = title,
        Description = description,
    });
    return ce.SaveChanges() == 1;
}
```

However, the SaveChanges method throws a Data.UpdateException which is thrown by a SqlClient.SqlException.  The latter says

"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'Listings.dbo.Ads'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated."

I wholeheartedly agree.  I just don't see why the ID should be null when it seems I set it immediately prior.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Maybe the ID column set as computed column in the edmx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else on my team configured the database to create its own ID's, and the issue is resolved.